# Failed to get access_token information through REST API in latest Google Cloud SDK 291.0.1

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gcloud

We are using the REST API call to get access token for our service account

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=$($token)
```

The call has been working properly and it started to fail with the error - failed to get access token:

```
2020-05-18T07:09:55.6584502Z Failed to get access_token information, see the exception bellow

2020-05-18T07:09:55.6585859Z System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

2020-05-18T07:09:55.6586831Z    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)

2020-05-18T07:09:55.6587756Z    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
```

After the investigation, the call might be failed in latest google cloud sdk.

- the call works

Google Cloud SDK 290.0.1
bq 2.0.56
core 2020.04.24
gsutil 4.49

- the call does not work

Google Cloud SDK 291.0.0
bq 2.0.57
core 2020.05.01
gsutil 4.50

Comment: any chance someone has been messing with your firewall / proxy server settings?

Comment: The error message says error 400 Bad Request, sounds like the server is not receiving the correct request format. Have you changed something n the way you authentic? It could be a good idea to review Google Oauth authentication process on https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent to double check the authentication on Google Servers and confirm the request format you need to pass to your server.

Comment: Thanks. I have done some test. The token access works properly with gcloud 290.0.1 and throws the error with gcloud 291.0.0. There are no other changes in our services, scripts, etc. Only change is the vms which are updated with latest windows os and gcloud tools.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend you to open an issue tracker here https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers to report this.